# Why is radical 10 (儿) called ひとあし and にんにょう?

Tags: radicals

For ひとあし I got mixed answers from different sources: some say it looks like human legs while according to others it's meaning + position, as for the other I could figure out why にん is there but is にょう a position indicator or is there anything more to it and does it have anything to do with actual legs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both あし and にょう are position indicators.

- [にょう](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/content/8.php) refers to the radical written from top left to bottom right. 辶(しんにょう・しんにゅう) is a typical instace.
- [あし](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/content/5.php) refers to the radical written on the bottom half.

儿 is mostly positioned as あし (as in 克), but sometimes as にょう like [兛](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjiy/13114.html). Hence the two names.

Comment: にょう in kanji is 繞{にょう} btw